# Detect white space or brackets at starting of string and particular substring from string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to detect occurrence of substring from main string but substring could start from space or ( opening bracket at starting  or closing bracket at end ) or . dot at end

I want to write one regular expression which detect all 4 condition and count the occurrence in php
EDIT - Thanks to JE SUIS i can check for start and end condition but it works only when $mainspring = "php" this does not work on " this is php".
It does not neglect the words before php.

Is there any way to neglect all string before out match and after our match?

```
    $mainString = "i love java but i want to learn php and this keyword ofphp should not be count because there is no space before php but this could be count (php)";
    $keyword = "php";
    $match =preg_match('/^[(\s]?'.$keywords.'[.)]?$/', $mainString);
    var_dump($match);
```

I don't know how can i write regular expression for this condition
Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: `$match =preg_match('/^\($keyword\)/', $mainString);` will match `$keyword` inside round brackets. You can work on this further to add more conditions as character classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
preg_match('/^[(\s]$keyword[.)]$/', $mainString, $match);
```

Where:

```
/           : regex delimiter
  ^         : begin of string
  [(\s]     : an open parenthesis or a space
  $keyword  : the keyword to find
  [.)]      : a dot or a close parenthesis
  $         : end of string
/           : regex delimiter
```

Note that the result of preg_match is a boolean, the matches are in the third parameter.

**Edit according to comment:**

If you want to match `$keyword` in the middle of the string, just remove the anchors `^` and `$`:

```
preg_match('/[(\s]$keyword[.)]/', $mainString, $match);
```

If you have some hexadecimal characters before and after:

```
preg_match('/[0-9a-fA-F][(\s]$keyword[.)][0-9a-fA-F]/', $mainString, $match);
```

If they are not mandatory:

```
preg_match('/[0-9a-fA-F]?[(\s]$keyword[.)][0-9a-fA-F]?/', $mainString, $match);
```

Comment: SUIS thanks for help.. but i want to add one more thing into it " before $keyword there could be another text or after keywords so can i change regex to something like this "[0-9a-fA-F] /^[(\s]$keyword[.)]$/ [0-9a-fA-F]  "
Because your regex works when i just put single keyword into MainString...et êtes-vous français?

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android: De rien. (Je suis effectivement français)

Comment: bien je habitat à Paris...enchanté.